# Dashboard targeting error in Laravel Breeze (involves Middleware with auth)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing some tests with Middleware to prevent the user not logged into the system from accessing pages that only logged in people can access. Apparently when I enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fighter` it returns to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`.

The problem occurs that when logging in I am redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fighter` and not to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard` which would be the correct.

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\FighterController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\MasterController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\DojoController;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
    
    // fighter folder
    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
        Route::controller(FighterController::class)->group(function() {
            Route::get('/fighter', 'index')->name('fighter.index');
            Route::get('/add-fighter', 'create')->name('fighter.create');
            Route::post('/add-fighter', 'store')->name('fighter.store');
            Route::get('/update-fighter/{id}', 'edit')->name('fighter.edit');
            Route::patch('/update-fighter/{id}', 'update')->name('fighter.update');
            Route::delete('/delete-fighter/{id}', 'destroy')->name('fighter.destroy');
        });
    });
    
    // master folder
    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
        Route::controller(MasterController::class)->group(function() {
            Route::get('/master', 'index')->name('master.index');
            Route::get('/add-master', 'create')->name('master.create');
            Route::post('/add-master', 'store')->name('master.store');
            Route::get('/update-master/{id}', 'edit')->name('fighter.edit');
            Route::patch('/update-master/{id}', 'update')->name('fighter.update');
            Route::delete('/delete-master/{id}', 'destroy')->name('fighter.destroy');
        });
    });
    
    // dojo folder
    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
        Route::controller(DojoController::class)->group(function() {
            Route::get('/dojo', 'index')->name('dojo.index');
            Route::get('/add-dojo', 'create')->name('dojo.create');
            Route::post('/add-dojo', 'store')->name('dojo.store');
            Route::get('/update-dojo/{id}', 'edit')->name('dojo.edit');
            Route::patch('/update-dojo/{id}', 'update')->name('dojo.update');
            Route::delete('/delete-dojo/{id}', 'destroy')->name('dojo.destroy');
        });
    });
    
    require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Comment: it will redirect to the 'intended' url which would be the URL you attempted to reach before getting redirected to the 'login' route ... you would have to go in and adjust the `AuthenticatedSessionController` to not provide this behavior and redirect to the specific URL/route you want

Comment: @lagbox i don't uderstand very well.

Comment: you need to edit the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController`'s `store` method ... you need to return the redirect you want

Comment: ```return redirect('/dashboard');```?

Comment: sure or `return redirect()->route('dashboard')` ... but you can always "try it and see" :)